# Home network file sharing

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, blocking

I am linked on a home network (I have a desktop and the others are on wireless) and have some files I don't want the rest of the house to share (mainly to do with my divorce and study). How can I stop them gaining access to my computer remotely? I am using XP operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way? Put a password on your computer, and don't let other know your password. If they don't have admin right over your PC, any files personal to you under your username is yours and yours alone.

If they have admin right over your PC, then you may want to check out [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to create an encrypted folder on your system that only you (who has the password) can decrypt and see the file.